# Get the ID of the cover photo for a Google Photos album

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

Using the Google Photos api, is there any way to get the ID of the cover photo of an album? So, for example, I could query the metadata on the cover photo? The only thing I see is the coverPhotoBaseUrl, which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are tracking this as a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/109655786

I agree, this is something that would be quite useful to include, in addition to the cover photo base URL. Please follow along on the issue tracker - you can 'star' the issue to be notified of any updates.

Unfortunately there is no work around at the moment.

Comment: This features was added, album objects now include `coverPhotoMediaItemId`.